# Updating missing values in excel-1 from values in excel-2 using Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 Excel sheets which have list of *Serial numbers* along with *Date of purchase*. Sheet-1 is master sheet, sheet-2 can be called a subset of that master sheet.

Not all *Serial numbers* in Sheet-1 are updated with *Date of purchase*. In Sheet-2 there are those *Serial numbers* which have their *Date of purchase* values missing in Sheet-1. Sheet-2 is completely updated with its *Serial number* and *Date of purchase* values.

I am trying to read all *Serial numbers* from Sheet-1, search those in Sheet-2, find the corresponding *Date of purchase* and update this value (wherever missing) in Sheet-1.

Following is the Layout of both sheets:
(Please note that the column names are a bit different in both sheets)

Sheet-1

```
Serial#   Date of purchase
111       01-Jun-2018
222       13-Jan-2018
333       (Blank)
444       (Blank)
555       11-Dec-2017
```

Sheet-2

```
Serial Number   purchase date
333             03-Feb-2019
444             19-Feb-2019
```

I am new to Pandas and first time trying to make a Python script using Pandas to achieve this. Here is the code that I've managed to write but its not working.

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df1 = pd.read_excel('Excel-1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel('Excel-2.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

df1['Date of purchase'] = df1['Serial#'].map(df2.set_index('Serial Number')['purchase date'])
```

**ERROR**

pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

**EDIT:**

- Both sheets have hundreds of entries, the layout I mentioned is just a sample.
- Both sheets have other columns also apart from the 2 listed in sample layout, the 2 mentioned are of interest to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input data are:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: sheet1=pd.DataFrame([[111,'01-Jun-2018'],[222,'13-Jan-2018'],[333],[444],[555,'11-Dec-2017']], columns=['Serial#','Date of purchase'])

In [3]: sheet1
Out[3]: 
   Serial# Date of purchase
0      111      01-Jun-2018
1      222      13-Jan-2018
2      333             None
3      444             None
4      555      11-Dec-2017

In [4]: sheet2=pd.DataFrame([[333,'03-Feb-2019'],[444,'19-Feb-2019']],columns=sheet1.columns)

In [5]: sheet2
Out[5]: 
   Serial# Date of purchase
0      333      03-Feb-2019
1      444      19-Feb-2019
```

You can proceed by [indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) your dataframes and using the [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method:

```
In [6]: sheet1.set_index('Serial#')

In [7]: sheet1['Date of purchase'].fillna(sheet2.set_index('Serial#')['Date of purchase'], inplace=True)

In [8]:

Out[8]: 
        Date of purchase
Serial#                 
111          01-Jun-2018
222          13-Jan-2018
333          03-Feb-2019
444          19-Feb-2019
555          11-Dec-2017
```

Comment: `sheet1=pd.DataFrame([[111,'01-Jun-2018'],[222,'13-Jan-2018'],[333],[444],[555,'11-Dec-2017']], columns=['Serial#','Date of purchase'])`

can you advise how it read it from Excel files, the Excel layouts I mentioned was just for sample. actual sheets have hundreds of entries.

Comment: If you read your Excel file with `pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx')`, I can guess what your data will look like. So I've take your sample data as an example.

Comment: I tried this method on with directly reading the excel files and I got an error. `pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError`.

Also, where in this code are we defining the _Date of purchase_ index (column) to look for the values as the sheets have other columns also. (edited the main question to specify that). Thanks.

Comment: I've modified my answer by expliciting the column to consider.

Comment: For the index error, you have to show or check yourself your data header before calling `set_index`.